# Contact Form Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to build contact form in Laravel 5.4. I'm almost succeeded but besides actual message, on my mail i'm getting the structure of the page (look screenshot). Can you help me with that? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hBbC.png)

my View Form:

```
                <div class="row">

      {{ Form:: open(array('action' => 'ContactController@getContactUsForm')) }}

      <ul class="errors">
      @foreach($errors->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)
      {{ $message }}
      @endforeach
      </ul>

      <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form:: textarea ('message', '', array('placeholder' => 'Message', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'message', 'rows' => '7' )) }}
      </div>




      <div class="modal-footer">
      {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
      {{ Form:: close() }}


      </div>
            </div>
```

And my Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Mail;
use Redirect;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
public function getContactUsForm(Request $request){
    //Get all the data and store it inside Store Varible
    $data = \Input::all();
    //$data = $request->message;
    //$data = $request->input('message');

    //Validation rules
    $rules = array (
        //'first_name' => 'required', uncomment if you want to grab this field
        //'email' => 'required|email',  uncomment if you want to grab this field
        'message' => 'required|min:5'
    );

    //Validate data
    $validator = Validator::make ($data, $rules);

    //If everything is correct than run passes.
    if ($validator -> passes()){



     Mail::send('support/contact', $data, function($message) use ($data)
            {
                //$message->from($data['email'] , $data['first_name']); uncomment if using first name and email fields
                $message->from('masha@mail.com', 'contact form');
    //email 'To' field: cahnge this to emails that you want to be notified.
    $message->to('masha@mail.com', 'Masha')->subject('Contact Form');

            });
            // Redirect to page
   return Redirect::route('contact')
    ->with('message', 'Your message has been sent. Thank You!');


            //return View::make('contact');
         }else{
   //return contact form with errors
            return Redirect::route('contact')
             ->with('error', 'Feedback must contain more than 5 characters. Try Again.');

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Nothing jumps out. Do a dd($request) right after the getContactUsForm function ( at the top of it ) and see if its the whole page or just the info passed. Its grabbing the view and sending that to you which is odd. Do you have another form on that page that might be interfering with it?

Comment: "Do you have another form on that page that might be interfering with it? "

No, it's only one form on the website.

Comment: Please `right click` on the page and view source, then click on any of the `css` links to see if you get to the file contents. If not then you know you links are broken. Work through each `css link`

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
  {{ Form:: close() }}
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
</div>
{{ Form:: close() }}
```

I think ordering break the structure.

Comment: Thanks for answer..  It's actually a good idea but didn't help me. ...
Think, maybe besides $data = \Input::all(); do something like $data = $request->input('message');

Comment: almost it's ordering problem. If you can copy the entire file to **Pastebin.com** or similar we can help you more further.

Comment: also, make sure you link the CSS file between **<head></head>**